# UnsatisfiedLinkError when running mvn jfx:run with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I have used the [Quickstart JavaFX archetype](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/basic-archetype.html) from the [JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/index.html) to create a Maven JavaFX project.

When running this project from the command line with "mvn jfx:run" everything works fine, but when I try to run it from IntelliJ (12.1.6) by creating a run configuration with "jfx:run" in the command line I get an UnsatisifedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.submitForLaterInvocation(WinApplication.java:215)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:101)
```

Any advice for how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the JRE /bin directory to the java.libary.path system property seems to work. This property used by the JVM for locating DLLs with native code.

Edit run/debug configuration and set the VM Options of the runner configuration to something like:

> -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin"